# Prove $\displaystyle \dfrac{n}{n + 1} > M$ whenever $n > N$ for some integer $N$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

Q: If $M$ is a positive number less than 1. Prove the terms in $\displaystyle \left\{\dfrac{n}{n + 1}\right\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ exceed $M$ for sufficiently large $n$; that is, prove $\displaystyle \dfrac{n}{n + 1} > M$ whenever $n > N$ for some integer $N$.

Not exactly sure how to prove this but here is my attempt so far.

By the definition of the limit, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n}{n + 1} > M$, we have $\forall M\in(0, 1)\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if
\begin{equation*}
n > N \hspace{1cm} \rightarrow \hspace{1cm} a_n > M
\end{equation*}

If $a_n = \dfrac{n}{n + 1}$, then we want to show that it exceeds $M$ as $n$ gets larger.

This is the part where I am kind of lost. I am not exactly sure how to proceed from here. Some tips or advice would be useful. Thanks

Comment: M is a confusing letter for a number less than 1. Rewrite as M= 1-\epsilon instead.

Comment: I would recommend trying to show that the sequence is strictly increasing first. Then you can show that the sequence converges to $1$. Since $M<1$, you can deduce that there exists an $N$ with the necessary property.

Comment: Write $n/(n+1) = 1 - 1/(n+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\frac{n}{n+1} = 1-\frac{1}{n+1}$. Fix an arbitrary $M < 1$ and write $M = 1 - \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. Using archimedian property...

Answer (score 2):

Both $M$ and $1-M$ are positive

if $$n > \frac{M}{1-M},$$  we see
$$  n+1 > \frac{1}{1-M}  $$
$$ \frac{1}{n+1}  < 1-M  $$
$$ -\frac{1}{n+1}  > M-1  $$
$$ 1-\frac{1}{n+1}  > M  $$
$$ \frac{n}{n+1}  > M  $$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac n{n+1} > M\iff n > M(n+1)\iff $

$n> Mn + M \iff n-Mn = n(1-M) > M$.

As $M < 1$ then $1- M > 0$ so

$n(1-M) > M \iff n \ge \frac M{1-M}$

So if $N$ is any integer $\ge \frac M{1-M}$ you get your result.

$n > N \ge \frac 1{1-M} \implies \frac n{n+1} > M$.

Comment: Doesn't $n > M(n + 1) \Leftrightarrow n > Mn + M$?

Comment: Yeah..... typo.... and followed all the way through.